# Longitudinal wave propagation in 3D

Tags: waves, acoustics, ultrasound

When a longitudinal wave is sent through a body, there is a strain in the emitted direction (x). What about the three-dimensional body with the strains in the direction perpendicular to the emitting direction (y, z). This strains must inevitably occur due to the "pressure wave". how can these be calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write the displacement vector as

$$\mathbf{u} = A \cos(kx)\cos(\omega t)(1, 0, 0)\, .$$

Thus, the strain tensor that is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_strain_theory#Infinitesimal_strain_tensor)

$$\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}[\nabla \mathbf{u} + (\nabla\mathbf{u})^T]\, ,$$

is

$$\epsilon = -Ak\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0&0\\
0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}\, .$$

Furthermore, the stress tensor, that for a [linear elastic material isotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law#Isotropic_materials) is defined as

$$\sigma = \lambda \mathrm{tr}(\epsilon) + 2\mu\epsilon\, ,$$

looks like

$$\sigma = -Ak\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)\left[\begin{matrix}\lambda + 2 \mu & 0 & 0\\0 & \lambda & 0\\0 & 0 & \lambda\end{matrix}\right]\, .$$

Comment: That was very helpful! What would the strains eyy and ezz be (or also the strain tensor)?

Comment: @Frank, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the renewed answer, @nicoguaro!!! I don't quite understand the strain tensor yet. The pressure wave of the longitudinal wave would inevitably also have to generate -small- strains in eyy and ezz, since the definition of Hook's law means that the compressive stresses in 3D also influence all vectors, right?

Comment: One more question about the stress tensor. Shouldn't it be like that:  <br/>  
\sigma = -Ak\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)\left[\begin{matrix}\lambda + 2 \mu & 0 & 0\\0 & \mu & 0\\0 & 0 & \mu\end{matrix}\right]\, .

Comment: @Frank, I don't think that your intuition is correct. I have added some details and hyperlinks for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the links! Sorry for asking again, but I still have a problem understanding the strain and stress tensor. The equations state that only the strain exx is present, but there are stresses in all directions. How can that be?

Comment: @Frank, That's how Hooke's law works. This is due to the Poisson effect (lateral contraction). If you are still confused about that, I suggest that you ask a new question.