# Longitudinal Wave in 3D - strain/stresses

Tags: waves, acoustics, elasticity, stress-strain

If a longitudinal wave is passed through a 3D isotropic body, the following strain tensor results [[Reference]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652859/longitudinal-wave-propagation-in-3d/652886?noredirect=1#comment1467698_652886):
[image]

This describes the strain in the x-direction while the strains in the y-and z-directions = 0.
If the stress tensor of the wave is now considered (Hookes Law), the result is [[Reference]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652859/longitudinal-wave-propagation-in-3d/652886?noredirect=1#comment1467698_652886):

[image]

How can it be that the longitudinal wave creates stresses in all directions, but strains in only one vector? 
Viewed the other way around, it could be argued that if there are stresses in all vectors, these would inevitably lead to strains in all directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems odd, but it might be a result of an assumption. The assumption of an infinitely large isotropic body means strains in the other directions are asymptotically zero.

Think of the particles inside the body as being constrained not to move along the *yz* directions. As a result, stresses would need to develop to enforce this constraint. This is why stress is 3D while strains are 1D only.